# RecyclerView Adapter returning zero child

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I wanted to get number of child of recyclerview list . i've tried below line but its returning zero everytime

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
```

Comment: Could you add some extra code, for example, how did you set the adapter and what values did you pass to it?

Comment: As Parag said, calling this would give you nothing if your adapter is not setup. Have you tried adding a breakpoint? You would probably see that your adapter item count IS 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter class - that one that inherits from `RecyclerView.Adapter` - must implement a method called `getItemCount()`, which should return an integer that is the size of the list you're trying to inflate.

You've probably forgot to return the right value from that method.

In Kotlin, it should look something like this:

```html
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

  var myItems: List<Item> = emptyList()
      set(value) {
          field = value
          notifyDataSetChanged()
      }

  // this method here tells the adapter that the item count
  // is equal to the size of the myItems list
  override fun getItemCount() = myItems.size
  
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) ...
  
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int)...

}
```